# Strange behavior in PowerShell function returning DataSet/DataTable

Tags: database, powershell

This is driving me crazy. I have a library I source from multiple scripts, which contains the following function:

```
function lib_open_dataset([string] $sql) {
    $ds = new-object "System.Data.DataSet"
    $da = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter" ($sql, $_conn_string)

    $record_count = $da.Fill($ds)

    return $ds
}
```

This is called pretty much everywhere and it works just fine, except that I normally have to do this:

```
$ds = lib_open_dataset($some_sql)
$table = $ds.Tables[0]
foreach ($row in $table.Rows) {
    # etc
}
```

So I created a new simple wrapper function to avoid the extra step of dereferencing the first table:

```
function lib_open_table([string] $sql) {
    $ds = lib_open_dataset $sql
    return $ds.Tables[0]
}
```

The problem is that what's being returned from here is the *Rows collection of the table* for some reason, not the *table* itself. This causes the `foreach` row loop written as above to fail with a "Cannot index into a null array." exception. After much trial and error I figured out this works:

```
foreach ($row in $table) {
    # etc
}
```

Note the difference between `$table.Rows` and just `$table` in the `foreach` statement. This **works**. Because `$table` actually points to the Rows collection. If the statement

```
return $ds.Tables[0]
```

is supposedly correct, why is the function returning a child collection of the table object instead of the table itself?

I'm guessing there's something in the way Powershell functions work that's causing this obviously, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the comma operator to wrap the rows collection in an array so that when the array is unrolled you wind up with the original rows collection e.g.:

```
function lib_open_table([string] $sql) {
    $ds = lib_open_dataset $sql    
    return ,$ds.Tables[0]
}
```

Essentially you can't prevent PowerShell from unrolling arrays/collections.  The best you can do is workaround that behavior by wrapping the array/collection within another, single element array.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. It's weird, but it worked :) 

Thanks a lot Keith.

Comment: What I don't understand is where the array gets unrolled. And why just the Rows collection, why not other property? Why not e.g. Columns property?

Comment: I'm no DataSet guru but I wonder if the data table returned is of type TypedTableBase<T> which is enumerable over T were T is DataRow.

Comment: Wow! This saved me so much time.  I thought I was going crazy. Where is the behavior documented?  Thank you so much!

Comment: This got me close, but Powershell actually returned an object of length = 6; to get the datatable I had to access the last value in the object:
`$returned_obj[5]`

Answer (score 13):

PowerShell special-cases the DataTable internally. It does not implement any of the usual suspect interfaces like ICollection, IList or IEnumerable which normally trigger the unrolling. You can dig into this a bit with:

```
PS> $dt = new-object data.datatable
PS> $dt -is [collections.ienumerable]
False
```

Yet:

```
PS> $e = [management.automation.languageprimitives]::GetEnumerator($dt)
PS> $e.gettype()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    RBTreeEnumerator                         System.ValueType
```

-Oisin

Comment: Thanks Oisin, I think this clarifies what's going on. What I wonder is _why_ PS is doing this at all?

Comment: @kprobst because powershell sucks. Just spent 3 hours with this issue, trying to debug this dataTable case.

Answer (score 4):

2 things you need to indeed focus on
a) prepend your returned object with the comma indeed
b) when you're filling your adaptor, make sure to either assign the outcome to a (disposalble) variable **or** do an Out-Null

I didn't do the Out-Null and even with a prepended comma, I kept getting a collection back (item 0=  number of rows from the query, item1= the datatable)
Drove my a bit crazy until I picked the Out-null parameter out.

Very weird IMHO, as I'm asking specifically to return the datatable but kept getting the collection back, even with the "," in front

```
function  Oracleconnection
{
  process
  {
  trap
    {
      Write-Host "error occured on oracle connection"
      Write-Host $_
      continue
    }
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName(“System.Data.OracleClient”) | out-null
    $connection = new-object system.data.oracleclient.oracleconnection( `
    "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost.host)(PORT=1800)) `
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=myservicename)));User Id=myid;Password=mypassword;");

    $query = "SELECT country, asset FROM table "
    $set = new-object system.data.dataset
    $adapter = new-object system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter ($query, $connection)
    $adapter.Fill($set) | Out-Null
    $table = new-object system.data.datatable
    $table = $set.Tables[0]
    return ,$table
  }
}
```

(Concepts from the Answer by [Keith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918455/12892553)!)