# How to stop PowerShell from unpacking an Enumerable object?

Tags: powershell

Working on a simple helper function in PowerShell that takes a couple of parameters and creates a custom Enumerable object and outputs that object to the pipeline.  The problem I am having is that PowerShell is always outputting a System.Array that contains the objects that are enumerated by my custom Enumerable object.  How can I keep PowerShell from unpacking the Enumerable object?

The code: http://gist.github.com/387768

Comment: PowerShell is sometimes too clever. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918190/strange-behavior-in-powershell-function-returning-dataset-datatable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change the line 46 from

```
$row
```

to

```
, $row
```

EDIT: as Johannes correctly pointed out, the unary operator comma creates an array with one member.

Comment: Explanation: This wraps whatever you want to return in an array (with just one element). This array will be unwrapped but its contents are not.