# Powershell 2.0 - SqlDataReader closing when passed into a function

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, sqldatareader

I am interacting with a set of custom .Net 2.0 assemblies, with Powershell 2.0, to automate a current task. I load all the required dlls and call a DAL method, in the dll, to retrieve a System.Data.SqlDataReader. When I pass the SqlDataReader into a constructor in the same custom assembly I receive a "Invalid attempt to call HasRows when reader is closed." exception.

**Code sample:**

```
dir D:\stuff\*.dll | foreach { [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($_.FullName) } | out-null
[CustomAssembly.DataConfig]::ConnectionString = "Valid Connection String"
$reader=[CustomAssembly.DAL.Thing]::Get(123)
new-object CustomAssembly.BusinessObjects.Thing($reader)
```

The $reader is open, and has data, before I call the Thing constructor.

I must be missing something, but I am not sure what it is.

**Edit 1:**

$reader appears to be read, and closed, anytime it is passed to a function, in powershell or in an assembly. Is there a way to prevent this?

**Edit 2:**

Powershell automatic unrolling strikes again

[How to stop PowerShell from unpacking an Enumerable object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756183/how-to-stop-powershell-from-unpacking-an-enumerable-object)

[Strange behavior in PowerShell function returning DataSet/DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918190/strange-behavior-in-powershell-function-returning-dataset-datatable)

The following modified code sample works by wrapping the result in a single element array, so the automatic unrolling does not affect the SqlDataReader. **Note the single comma after the "$reader=" statement. That is not a typo.**

```
dir D:\stuff\*.dll | foreach { [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom($_.FullName) } | out-null
[CustomAssembly.DataConfig]::ConnectionString = "Valid Connection String"
$reader=,[CustomAssembly.DAL.Thing]::Get(123)
new-object CustomAssembly.BusinessObjects.Thing($reader)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into similar issues some time ago. Look at this code:

I create my own Enumerator that prints some information about when it is called. It's same as your `SqlDataReader` that (I think) implements `IEnumerator` as well.

```
PS> Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    public class MyEnumerator2 : IEnumerator
    {
        private int _count = 10;
        private Random r = new Random();

        public MyEnumerator2(int count)
        {
            _count = count;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Moving!");
            _count--;
            return _count >= 0;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object Current
        {
            get
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Current!");
                return r.Next();
            }
        }
    }
"@
```

Then let's create an object of the type and try to output it:

```
PS> $mye = New-Object MyEnumerator2 5
PS> $mye | % -begin { write-host 'starting' } -Process { write-host 'next is ' $_ }
starting
Moving!
Current!
next is  2081278528
Moving!
Current!
next is  2000135673
Moving!
Current!
next is  692162542
Moving!
Current!
next is  1531746038
Moving!
Current!
next is  1550381634
Moving!
```

Everything is as expected. But.. now

```
PS> function iteratemye($o) {
    $o | % -begin { write-host 'starting' } -Process { write-host 'next is ' $_ }
}
PS> $mye = New-Object MyEnumerator2 5
PS> iteratemye $mye
Moving!
Current!
Moving!
Current!
Moving!
Current!
Moving!
Current!
Moving!
Current!
Moving!
starting
Moving!
```

If you pass this enumerator to a function, it is read **before it reaches the body**. That's very bad.

So have a look at your code. If you use some function like my `iteratemye`, that's the cause of your problems.

Update: it doesn't implement `IEnumerator`, but `IEnumerable`.
I see that you just pass the object to some constructor, which is not the same problem I had, but I believe PowerShell will still try to get enumerator and do some magic.

Comment: That seems to be the case with the SqlDataReader. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Looks like I have to wrap it in another array, because there is no way to prevent it.