# PowerShell function won't return object

Tags: powershell, object, return

I have a simple function that creates a generic List:

```
function test()
{
    $genericType = [Type] "System.Collections.Generic.List``1"
    [type[]] $typedParameters = ,"System.String"
    $closedType = $genericType.MakeGenericType($typedParameters)
    [Activator]::CreateInstance($closedType)
}

$a = test
```

The problem is that `$a` is always null no matter what I try.  If I execute the same code outside of the function it works properly.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IMHO that's pitfall #1. If you return an object from the function that is somehow enumerable (I don't know exactly if implementing `IEnumerable` is the only case), PowerShell unrolls the object and returns the items in that.

Your newly created list was empty, so nothing was returned. To make it work just use this:

```
,[Activator]::CreateInstance($closedType)
```

That will make an one item array that gets unrolled and the item (the generic list) is assigned to `$a`.

**Further info**

Here is list of similar question that will help you to understand what's going on:

- [Powershell pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803521/powershell-pitfalls)
- [Avoiding Agnostic Jagged Array Flattening in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463190/avoiding-agnostic-jagged-array-flattening-in-powershell)
- [Strange behavior in PowerShell function returning DataSet/DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918190/strange-behavior-in-powershell-function-returning-dataset-datatable)
- [What determines whether the Powershell pipeline will unroll a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827862/what-determines-whether-the-powershell-pipeline-will-unroll-a-collection)

---

*Note*: you dont need to declare the function header with parenthesis. If you need to add parameters, the function will look like this:

```
function test {
 param($myParameter, $myParameter2)
}
```

or

```
function  {
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=true, Position=0)]$myParameter,
  ... again $myParameter2)
...
```

Comment: The comma!  D'oh. Thanks, I'll get that right one of these days.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way to work with generics. This does not directly solve the [Activator] approach though

```
Function test
{
    New-Object "system.collections.generic.list[string]"
}

(test).gettype()
```