# Loading a serialized DataTable in PowerShell - Gives back array of DataRows not a DataTable

Tags: powershell, xml-serialization, datatable, xml-deserialization

I'm trying to save and load a DataTable in PowerShell.
I save it like this:

```
$dt | Export-CliXml -path "c:\exports\data.xml"
```

and load it like this:

```
$dt = Import-CliXml -path "c:\exports\data.xml"
```

But the type I get back is an array of Rows rather than a DataTable!
This is causing me major problems as it needs to be passed into a function which requires a DataTable, and it cannot be cast to one.

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known trap: PowerShell processes your `DataTable`  as a collection of `DataRow` items. That is the very first command

```
$dt | Export-CliXml -path "c:\exports\data.xml"
```

already “forgets” the data table. You may take a look at the output file, it starts with `DataRow`:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Data.DataRow</T>
```

To avoid this effect, use the `,` operator (it looks funny but that’s exactly how it works):

```
, $dt | Export-CliXml -path "c:\exports\data.xml"
```

As a result, the output file now starts with `DataTable`:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>System.Data.DataTable</T>
```

After that you can import the table back:

```
$dt = Import-CliXml -path "c:\exports\data.xml"
```

Let’s check it:

```
$dt | Get-Member
# output:
TypeName: Deserialized.System.Data.DataRow
…
```

We can see the same effect (`DataRow` instead of `DataTable`). Thus, the correct command is with `,`:

```
, $dt | Get-Member
# output:
TypeName: Deserialized.System.Data.DataTable
…
```

So, we really dehydrate a `DataTable` in this way.

===

EDIT: This effect is known as *unrolling*. PowerShell tends to unroll collections. The comma operator creates an array of a single item. PowerShell unrolls this array, too, but it does not unroll its items (our `DataTable`).

Here is a very similar question:

[Strange behavior in PowerShell function returning DataSet/DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918190/strange-behavior-in-powershell-function-returning-dataset-datatable)

Comment: Thanks, but this still leaves me with a problem:
$dt2 = ,(Import-CliXml -path "c:\exports\data.xml")
$dt2.GetType().Name
Object[]
$dt2 | Get-Member
TypeName: Deserialized.System.Data.DataTable

Comment: What is the problem in this? (BTW, you do something different than I suggested).

Comment: If I save the table in the way you say, then import with:

$dt = Import-CliXml -path "c:\exports\data.xml"

$dt.GetType() gives the error:

"Method invocation failed because [Deserialized.System.Data.DataTable] doesn't contain a method named 'GetType'"

When I pass $dt into my function which requires a DataTable, I get:

Cannot convert the "System.Collections.ArrayList" value of type "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "System
.Data.DataTable".

Comment: This is another question, @Chris, perhaps not suitable for discussion in these comments. How do you send $dt to your function? How does your function look like? Why do you think it is supposed to work with deserialized by PowerShell DataTable?

Comment: Perhaps PowerShell Clixml serialization should not be used in this particular case. I would recommend you to use DataTable.WriteXml/ReadXml methods for saving and restoring table data *exactly* as they are. Do not deserialize the table, use a new one and call ReadXml on it.

Comment: Thanks Roman, I have managed to get it to work using the WriteXml and ReadXml functions as you suggested. However I am still shocked that a deserialized object in PowerShell is not identical to the original object.

Comment: Yes, this is confusing. Clixml export/import has nothing to do with classic serialization.

Comment: I think serialization in .NET in general is weak.